# Rotate Object OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, powervr-sgx, dm814x

we are using the following code to plot a BMP image in OpenGL ES 2.0: 
(x1,y1 is lower left coordinates, and x2,y2 are top right coordinates of the objects on the screen, tempimage data is the pointer to bmp image information stored)

```
struct
{
  GLuint uiId;
  GLuint uiLowerLeftLoc;
  GLuint uiScaleMatrixLoc;
  GLuint auiLoc[eNumUniforms];
}
m_ShaderProgram;

glUniform2f(m_ShaderProgram.uiLowerLeftLoc, x1, y1);
float afMatrix[4] = { x2 - x1, 0, 0, y2 - y1 };
glUniformMatrix2fv(m_ShaderProgram.uiScaleMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, afMatrix);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uiTexForeground);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tempimagedata);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uiVbo);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ARRAY, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

I want to rotate the object in terms of angles. How this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

You should send a rotation/transfom-matrix to the shader you're using before rendering your mesh. Within your vertex shader, multiply the coordinates by the matrix.

This site is good for understanding the basics of rendering with matrices (it uses C++ and GLM): http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: I am new to the OpenGL. As per the understanding, MVP matrix used is for 3D rotation (please correct me if I am wrong), which is quite complex as of now. Is there any method for just 2D rotation of the objects ? 

currently we are plotting PNG/JPEG/BMP picture as well as custom boxes in 2D plane. This is what we want to rotate. we are calculating the vertex coordinates for theses objects, (4 set coordinates for box, 2 set for BMP/JPEG/PNG). We tried to calculate coordinates and tried to plot with new orientation, but the shader applying is not getting properly.

Can you help on this ?

Comment: For rotation, a matrix is the way to go. The MVP system should still be used even for 2D. Although, you could narrow translation and scale to x and y, and for rotation just implement the z-rotation matrix.

Comment: The important thing to remember is that when rotation is applied on a mesh you are rendering, it will rotate around it's local origin. This is why translation has to be applied in the shader, and why you cannot change the vertex coordinates externally. Otherwise, the origin would be shifted away from the mesh, and it would seemingly circulate around the origin. A lot of people forget this, and it could be a reason for the incorrect result.

Comment: Thanks SporreKing.
We are on the way to control the vertex coordinates externally.